# Intellij idea svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

when I commit or  update ,it successes,but when I want to show history,it fails.

[image]

Comment: Problems while loading file history: svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
  svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found

Answer (score 8):

What fixed this for me was:

Under File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion > Presentation:
Uncheck "Show merge source in history and annotations"

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem with IntelliJ 16.

I came around the problem by switching off "Use command line client" in the general Subversion configuration in IntelliJ for the project, and additionally checking out the project using repo format 1.7 (instead of 1.8).